# Microsoft Word 2007 "has insufficient memory"

Tags: memory, microsoft-word-2007

When we open any local or network Word document in Word 2007, we receive an error:

> Word has insufficient memory.  Do you want to save document1 as
>   rescued document?

The machine has 8GB of RAM, and equivalent in page file.  I have performed the following without resolving the issue:

- Renamed normal.dotm.
- Performed Office Diagnostics, which found and repaired 1 issue.
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled Word 2007.
- There was no HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Data key to delete.  (There was no Word entry under Office)
- There was no HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options key to delete.
- There were no Startup items to rename/delete in %programfiles%\Microsoft\Office\Office12\Startup\
- There were no COM Add-ins to delete in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins

This occurs with every document.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the list of things that you had already tried; just working my way through them now.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you mention that it happens with every document, we know it is probably the program in some form or another.

I would try ininstalling it one more time with the help of this document.

After I would then run CCleaner, using both the "Cleaner" an the Registry cleaner.

Comment: What operating system is it on? There are also Microsoft programs, designed to check the readiness of a system for a service pack, and these programs fix any inconsistencies along the way.